# Show System Time in WPF: Dispatcher timer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am displaying time in my application using(basically in a label Datetime.Now formatted as hh:mm:ss tt) using a  DispatcherTimer.

```
_timer = new DispatcherTimer {Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)};
                _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
                _timer.Start();

private void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    var nowUserSelected =
                        TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(now,
                            (DataContext as MainViewModel)?.UserSelectedTimeZone ?? TimeZoneInfo.Local);
                    ClockCurrent.Text = $"{nowUserSelected:hh:mm:ss tt}";
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    Log.Error("Error occurred while reporting time", exp);
                }
            }
```

The issue is that if the user opens a the Clock from the task bar(if you click on the time in the task bar there is pop up which displays the current time including seconds) sometimes the time in my app appears to be off by one second(sometimes!). Which I believe could be  happening because the timer must be set to tick every second from the current time which could be **10:50:53 PM and 950 ms** and it might be lets say and then it ticks every 54 and 950 ms ..... ms and so on , and since I am only displaying time till seconds it gives the illusion i am behind a whole second.

What is the recommended way to show the time which matches the time shown by the task bar, maybe set timer interval to tick every 500 ms ?

Comment: Just use a shorter interval, maybe even 200 ms. The additional work load is neglectable. You could also keep the current second in a field and compare it to the new value after calling DateTime.Now. Only if it has changed, do the conversion and label update.

Answer (score 0):

Check the ms when you are starting. Do first refresh right after full second, next refreshes each second

Even better: at the end of UI update you determine when the next UI update must happen.

Comment: This doesn't work. The timer is not ticking precisely every 1000 ms, it ticks roughly every 1000 ms, it can drift away. If you have heavy work on the UI thread, very soon your ticking event can be fired at the middle of a second.

Comment: If the tick frequency depends on UI load or other factors, then the only viable solution is to determine the next update on every iteration

Comment: remember all this runs on the UI thread, this had better be fast, without blocking the execution (`Thread.Sleep`) or switching context (`await Task.Delay()`); I don't think your goal - which is let the tick event fired at the very beginning of a second -is viable, at least cannot be easily done. Use shorter interval (~ 200 ms) would be easier.

Comment: My Expectation on `DispatchTimer` is that it fieres *ecery second* (depending on cpu architecture, but not depending on the duration of the method execution. And I'm **not** talking about any blocking operation.

Answer (score 0):

@iPirat is correct, but I guess others did not understand what he meant, so let me first explain what is the problem and then how to solve it.

The `DispatcherTimer` runs on the WPF GUI thread. The advantage of this is that the code of `DispatcherTimer.Tick` can access any WPF control. The disadvantage is that once the 1 second since the last tick has expired, the WPF GUI thread might be busy with something else and the tick fires few milliseconds later. The next time Tick gets execute, there will be another small delay and this accumulates until the summed up delay becomes bigger than 1 second and you "loose" one tick.

You can prevent that by changing `DispatcherTimer.Interval` during each tick. If you want a tick every 1000 milliseconds and the tick was executed x milliseconds too late, you set `DispatcherTimer.Interval` to 1000-x milliseconds.

```
const int constantInterval = 1000;//milliseconds

private void Timer_Tick(object? sender, EventArgs e) {
  var now = DateTime.Now;
  var nowMilliseconds = (int)now.TimeOfDay.TotalMilliseconds;
  var timerInterval = constantInterval - 
   nowMilliseconds%constantInterval + 5;//5: sometimes the tick comes few millisecs early
  timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timerInterval);
}
```

By the way, you might want to increase the priority like this `DispatcherTimer  timer = new DispatcherTimer (DispatcherPriority.Input);`. This will make the delays a bit smaller, but the GUI gets still rendered fast enugh.

For more details see my article on CodeProject: [Improving the WPF DispatcherTimer Precision](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5323994/Improving-the-WPF-DispatcherTimer-Precision)